# Query regarding app using Internet connection

Tags: android

I have an application that uses Internet connection but when there is no internet connection available the application stop responding. Can anyone help on how i can resolve this problem. What I have thought that i can display an error when there no internet connection available but I dont know the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my HTTPclass.java class, how I did that, I have a method connect(url) that takes a String of url and connects it, if connection is received it responds and gives the `responseCode = 200` or `HTTP.OK`, and if the connection is not connected I handle a catch block and set the `responseCode = -1` which means its not connected.

So, you can do something like that only. When responsecode is -1 you can show the Message that "Internet Not Connected".

```
public class HTTPClass
{
    private static int responseCode = -1;
    private static HttpURLConnection httpconn = null;        
    private static URLConnection conn = null;
    private static URL urlobj;

    public static int connect(String url) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            urlobj = new URL(url);
            conn = urlobj.openConnection();
            httpconn= (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpconn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpconn.setDoInput(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            responseCode = httpconn.getResponseCode();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            responseCode = -1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Required permission is :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

***Check Internet connection for each request***

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Use above method  as

```
if(isOnline()) {
   //Write code of request
} else {
   showDialog("Internet connection error", "Connection is not available.")
}
```

Show dialog method

```
private void showDialog(String title, String text) {
        // Access denied. Show dialogue to user
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
        alertbox.setTitle(title);
        alertbox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        alertbox.setMessage(text);
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                //finish(); //DO nothing
            }
        });
        alertbox.show();
    }
```

***Edited*** :
Replace YOUR_ACTIVITY.this with activity name in which your are using this code.

Comment: hey thanks man I tried it but it is not showing the alert box when the internet connection is not available.

Comment: yes but instead of alert box now I am trying the Toast but still it is not getting displayed.

Comment: This means else part of my code is not executing.......... put logs and check what is the problem. And also check that your emulator/ Device having no connection(For executing else block).

Comment: Ya I had checked it without connection only.

Comment: Strange! And I just checked it again and its working for all my 6 emulators and 3 devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can show an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to show the user that there is no internet connection.And if your application can't go on without connection,after clickin cancel button in AlertDialog, you can finish your activity and close the application.